# Django replace all occurrences [name] with auctual contact.name

Tags: django

I'm looking to be pointed in the right direction. As I loop all my contacts I somehow want to parse 'batch.content' (which holds my message). I want to find any occurrence of [name] in the text and replace with the contact.name.

```
  for e in Contact.objects.filter(contact_owner=batch.user, group=batch.group):
            msg = Message.objects.create(
                recipient_number=e.mobile,
                content=batch.content,
                sender=e.contact_owner,
                billee=batch.user
            )
```

My question is, how do I parse the string 'batch.content' and replace all occurrences of [name]? An example using my code would be really helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
batch.content.replace('[name]', contact.name)
```

Comment: thats gives typeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, instancemethod found

Comment: That's for you to fix. If contact.name is an instancemethod, feed it something that actually is the string you want to replace. This is a simple string substitution. `"X Y Z".replace("X", 'A STRING')` It is your responsibility to figure out what it is you actually want to replace X with.